Problema con el nuevo Input Service de Unity y WasPressedThisFrame()
He estado trabajando últimamente con el nuevo Unity Input Service, el problema es que mientras programaba el salto usé la función isPressed(), pero ahora quiero cambiarla para que solo salte cuando el jugador presione una vez más, sin mantenerlo presionado, así que use WasPressedThisFrame(), solo que encontré un nuevo problema, y por las pruebas que estuve haciendo si pasa todas las condicionales y llega a los calculos pero estos se suman de poco en poco, hasta que después de presionar enter 3 veces, que es cuando llega 1.2 de altura y por alguna razón salta, todo esto paso solamente con la funcion de WasPressedThisFrame(), no sé como puedo hacer los cálculos correctamente o alguna alternativa para que se ejecute la función sin tener que mantenerla presionada.
Adjunto código
Cabe señalar que si llega al lugar donde se realizan los cálculos de fallSpeed
private void HandleJump()
{
    if (controls.Player.Jump.IsPressed() && isGrounded && canStandUp && !menu.isActive)
    {
        if (isCrouching)
            StartCoroutine(CheckCrouch());
        else fallSpeed = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * 4f * -gravity);
    }
}

private void Update()
{
    if (!menu.isActive)
        HandleMouse(controls.Player.Look.ReadValue<Vector2>());
    HandleMovement(controls.Player.Movement.ReadValue<Vector2>());

    menu.HandleMenu();

    // Throw a raycast that verifies if has grounded
    isGrounded = Physics.BoxCast(groundCheck.transform.position, new Vector3(0.5f, 0.065f, 0.5f), Vector3.down, Quaternion.identity, player.skinWidth + .01f);
}

private void HandleMovement(Vector2 pos)
{
    if (!menu.isRespawning)
    {
        HandleRun();

        if (!menu.isActive)
        {
            HandleCrouch();

            movementInput.x = pos.x;
            movementInput.y = 0;
            movementInput.z = pos.y;
        }
        else movementInput = Vector3.zero;

        if (movementInput.magnitude > 1)
            movementInput.Normalize();

        Vector3 moveDirection = playerCamera.transform.TransformDirection(movementInput);
        moveDirection.y = 0;
        moveDirection.Normalize();

        CalculateGravity();
        HandleJump();

        moveDirection.y = fallSpeed;
        player.Move(Time.deltaTime * currentSpeed * moveDirection);

        HandleFootsteps();
    }
}


Hola Alan, bienvenido, esto es SOes, el idioma soportado es el español, te sugiero que traduzcas tu pregunta, así evitarás recibir votos negativos y/o el cierre de la misma.
